# Which HTTP response code is most suitable for this situation?

Tags: http, rest, restful-architecture

I'am writing an API to make users can subscribe to things. An user can subscribe to anything via submitting a `POST` something like this:

```
{
    "item_id": "c13",
    "requested_status": "subscriber",
    "sure": true,
}
```

Here you can see a `sure` parameter. I'am using this to avoid making subscriptions accidentaly. If client sends that info without `sure` parameter API rejects that request to make GUI ask "are sure to subscribe this?". If user confirms, same post happens again with `sure` parameter. And subscription (or unsubscription) happens.

So, when I am rejecting that request because there is no `sure` parameter. Which response code should I use? I thought 400 (bad request) can be used but not sure.

Thanks for you response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP codes are codes with a pure technical meaning. What you want is not a technical problem and shouldn't be handled with technical means.

Since the reponse was received and contained technically correct values (not the same as functional valid values!), you should send a 200 - OK status. The content of your response should be the action to perform next. In this case, ask the user if he/she is sure.

If you work with [Post-Redirect-Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get), a 303 - See Other status is your best option.

Comment: You might want to check this URL: http://odino.org/don-t-rape-http-if-none-match-the-412-http-status-code/. It is when a pre-condition in the HTTP header was not satisfied.